# How to add a line to the bottom of my table?

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm using Java Swing with JasperReports. In Jasper I have items that are in `Band: Details.` I created around them lines (top, left, right). The problem is the line at the bottom.

**Report Layout**

[image: My report layout]

When I put in Page footer and Run it - the line doesn't close the square. How I can close this square and independently of how many items I have?

**Current output, with expect result**

[image: Expected outcome]

Comment: Column footer, page footer, and last page footer bands are statically sized.

Comment: 1.Add border to detail band.
This way prints border at every detail band.

2.Use (dummy) group footer instead of page footer.
This way prints closing border only last page.

3.Use Background band.

Comment: @YasuyukiUno It works with dummy. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved, by adding Group.
I have Band: Detail, and there lines in the top and on the botton of the detail (to close the rectangle). Then I added Group, under Detail Band and that's all

P.S. I was follow @YasuyukiUno instructions

[image]

Answer (score 5):

To add the border at **end of table in each page** use the `columnFooter` band and set `isFloatColumnFooter="true"` on `jasperReport` tag

**Example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Example" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="500" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="30" bottomMargin="30"  isFloatColumnFooter="true" uuid="43c90ca5-f3c3-4dda-8423-9ff1442f90e3">
    .....
   <columnFooter>
    <band height="2">
        <line>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="1" uuid="1c32f6e5-414a-428d-8b06-35cd80e8dff6"/>
        </line>
    </band>
   </columnFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

To add the border at the **end of table** (not on each page if it overflows) use a dummy group and the `groupFooter` band

**Example**

```
<group name="lastBorderLine">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA["dummy"]]></groupExpression>  
    <groupFooter>
        <band height="2">
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="1" uuid="3510fdc6-0f30-4ec9-8e17-ac51fd4012c1"/>
            </line>
        </band>
    </groupFooter>
</group>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a style with a border bottom and apply it to the table. This adds a line to the bottom of the table on each page.

Comment: This was a simpler solution than the other one for me